# Merge nginx location blocks

Tags: nginx

is there a way to have the same configuration for `/api/*` and `/api/private/*`?
I tried putting the `/api/private/` location block inside the one from `/api/`, but that returns 404s for `/api/private/`.
Thanks.

```
worker_processes 5;
error_log /dev/stderr info;
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
daemon off;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
    access_log /dev/stdout combined;

    root /assets;

    server_tokens off;

    server {
        listen 8080 default;
        server_name _;
        server_tokens off;

        client_body_timeout 12;
        client_header_timeout 12;
        keepalive_timeout 15;
        send_timeout 10;

        include /mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_http_version 1.0;
        gzip_comp_level 5;
        gzip_min_length 512;
        gzip_buffers 4 8k;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types
        # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/x-component
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-font-opentype
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon;

        client_body_temp_path /tmp/clientbody;
        proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy;
        fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi;
        uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi;
        scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi;

        # no framing
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;

        # no mime sniff
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

        # enable browser XSS protection
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

        # Remove Referer headers
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer";

        # Add CORS headers
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://$host";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,HEAD";

        # Add Feature Policy header
        add_header Feature-Policy "geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; notifications 'none'; push 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; vibrate 'none'; fullscreen 'none'; payment 'none';";

        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
            return 444;
        }

        location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
          expires 1d;
          add_header Cache-Control "private";
        }

        location /_health {
            access_log off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
            stub_status;
        }

        location /api/private/ {
            proxy_read_timeout          30m;
            send_timeout                30m;
            client_max_body_size        1000M;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_cf_connecting_ip;
            proxy_pass http://api:8080/;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_cf_connecting_ip;
            proxy_pass http://api:8080/;
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally I would like to do:

```
        location /api/ {
            location /api/private/ {
                proxy_read_timeout          30m;
                send_timeout                30m;
                client_max_body_size        1000M;
            }
            
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_cf_connecting_ip;
            proxy_pass http://api:8080/;
        }
```

Comment: You could use a `rewrite...break` statement to manage the differences to the `proxy_pass` statement. For example: `rewrite ^/api(?:/private)?(.*)$ $1 break;`

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of your question. Does your original posted configuration actually work? It looks like it should be working.